The image read by cv2.imread() in the current folder is always None, and the image under the current file does not contain a Chinese path
The image read by cv2.imread() in the current folder is always None, and the image under the current file does not contain a Chinese path.
The code is very simple, just use this function to read the pictures in the current folder, but it always returns None.
python
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('./3.png')
print(img)

There is only one .py file and one 3.png under the current folder. I simply read it, but the read result is always None. There is no Chinese path to this file, and I really can't figure it out. OpenCV version is 4.9.0

Change the folder name and remove the ".", this messes with the naming of the file. the code is expecting one point as a delimiter to identify the type of the image.

I was wrong about opencv reading the image using the extension But still I think the problem lies in './3.png'. Copy the image to where your script is running and test the reading just using cv2.imread("3.png")

Thank you very much for everyone's method, I found a solution.
The picture I read was originally a gif. I directly changed the suffix of the file to .png on the file manager under windows, so there was a problem when reading it. It is clearly stated in OpenCV that imread cannot read gif files. So I restored the image to a gif and then used Python encoding to keep the first frame of the gif as a png image, so that when I read the image again, there would be no problem of not being able to read it.

Hey, post the comment as an answer and accept it. This way others can also easily find it!
